# i wanted to scrape the text inside the h2 tag containing img tag and ordinary the text with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, request

here is the the part i want to scrape, just the address

```
<h4>
            <img alt="icon" src="/assets/assets/img/agent-result/8fd82ccea302741620de4526126aa8d1-map-marker.png" title="icon"/>
            Plot 9, Olawale Onitiri Cole street,lekki phase 1, Lagos
           </h4>
```

here is my code

```
response = requests.get('https://www.propertypro.ng/agents',headers={"user-agent":"mozilla/5.0(x11; ubuntu; Linux x86_64;rv:61.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"})
data= BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
page_one = data.find_all('div',class_='agent-rp-area')
for item in page_one:
    for link in item.find("h4"):
         page_one_.append(link.string)
```

and this is the error am having
its giving me the image tag and the text

Comment: What error do you get running the script?

Comment: you forgot to add (full) error message in question. Don't expect that we will run code to see error message. Besides code can work correctly on out computers.

Comment: it seems this page uses JavaScript to add items but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you use `find()` in wrong way.

`find` gives only one element (or `None`) and you shouldn't use it with `for`-loop but

```
 link = item.find("h4")
```

If you use `for`-loop then it doesn't get value from `find()` but from `find().children` and it has problem to get text from one of children.

---

Second problem is that you should use rather `.text` or `.get_text()`/`.get_text(strip=True)` instead of `.string`

```
 print(link.text)
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "mozilla/5.0(x11; ubuntu; Linux x86_64;rv:61.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
}

url = 'https://www.propertypro.ng/agents'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

page_one = soup.find_all('div', class_='agent-rp-area')

for item in page_one:
    link = item.find("h4")
    if link:
        text = link.text.strip() 
        print('text:', text)
```

Result:

```
text: NO. 62, KUDIRAT ABIOLA ROAD, IKEJA, Lagos
text: Plot 9, Olawale Onitiri Cole street,lekki phase 1, Lagos
text: 
text: 1 towry close off idejo street victoria island, Lagos
text: 13 Akpomudje Street, Ago Palace Way, Okota, Lagos
text: C193 Ikota Shopping Complex VGC, Lagos
text: Lagos
text: 34, AJOSE STREET OFF JUBRIL MARTIN'S STREET LAWANSON. , Lagos
text: 
text: Obafemi Awolowo Way, Lagos
text: 
text: Suite 230, Block C, Road 2, Ikota Shopping Complex, VGC, Lekki, Lagos, Lagos
text: 46 liasu road , Lagos
text: 
text: 23 Furo Ezimora Street,Lekki Phase 1, Lagos
text: 
text: 120/12 Bosun Adekoya Street, Lekki Phase 1 (Oceanside), Lagos, Lagos
text: 
text: 15, TAIWO KOYA STREET, OFF SURA MOGAJI, Lagos
text: Lekki Expressway, Lagos
```